# Почему скопировать текст мне удается?

Tags: javascript

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div');

div.addEventListener('copy', function(e){
  console.log('копирование запрещено');
})
```

```html
<div class="d">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae at sint harum ullam explicabo accusamus ea vero recusandae ipsa architecto voluptas maiores possimus, et tempora, sapiente deserunt consequuntur quo! Minima nesciunt blanditiis sapiente excepturi deleniti, nihil possimus aliquam natus quas voluptatibus distinctio sed optio aspernatur obcaecati consequuntur veniam cum vel amet nobis error autem assumenda quo. Autem labore excepturi necessitatibus tenetur? Praesentium aut, illo vero reiciendis, architecto sunt, animi voluptas obcaecati in aperiam reprehenderit fugit minima ab soluta. Totam dolor id, aspernatur reiciendis possimus accusantium libero, expedita quas. Neque nemo, voluptates ex tempora, fugiat aperiam voluptate ipsa quasi. Quo, recusandae.</div>

<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">
  
</textarea>
```

1. Я правом кликом мыши вызываю меню и выбираю скопировать
2. В консоль выводит копирование запрещено
3. Затем я вставляю текст который якобы запрещен в textarea
4. По факту (как я понимаю) мне удалось скопировать текст и событие не сработало
5. что делать ?

Comment: А где вы запретили копирование? Даже в коде js не видно, просто обработчик копирования, без всяких запретов.

Comment: @Andrey Mihalev 1) я думал событие само запрещает 2) тогда как запретить ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте `e.preventDefault(); return false;` в обработчик события copy.

Comment: e.preventDefault(); return false; отменяют действия по умолчанию почему тогда они срабатывают если мы пытаемся скопировать сознательно ?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю вопрос. Если вы хотите запретить копирование текста - вам необходимо отменить дефолтную реакцию браузера на событие, что можно сделать вышеуказанным кодом.

Comment: @Leks само создание обработчика события не отменяет поведение по умолчанию. Поэтому нужно на прямую в коде отменять это поведение

Comment: @STY я правильно тогда понял copy событие которое срабатывает при попытке копирования; по умолчанию текст копируется; и таким кодом e.preventDefault(); return false; мы его отменяем ?

Comment: @ThisMan извините не успел прочитать Ваш комментарий сам коммент написал правильно ?

Comment: @Leks всё правильно

Comment: @STY спасибо что ответили на вопросы